# WiredTiger cpp file not found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I've hit some strange behavior trying to use a MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04. This is a virtual machine in Azure. I was able to set up Mongo and put data into a collection, so no issue there. Recently, Mongo went quiet and started throwing errors.
The error I'm currently navigating is the following:

```
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "*.*.*.*", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-08-07T16:54:42.402+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=2972M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-08-07T16:54:43.244+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31803) [1533660883:244872][31678:0x7f6528cca9c0], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found
2018-08-07T16:54:43.266+0000 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31803: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 413
```

I'm trying to figure out where that `wiredtiger_ky_engine.cpp` file is supposed to go. I would think it would have been pulled in from the github repo during setup. It's throwing a relative path, so I feel like I should be able to find the cwd of the mongo engine to place it there, however, that seems a bit hacky.

Has anyone seen this issue before and if so, what's a good fix?

*EDIT:*
When I try to find the process id, it looks like mongo runs in the root directory:

```
sudo service mongod start && sudo pwdx $(pgrep mongod)
31190: /
```

I made the directory there to no avail, the error message still persists:

```
E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31803: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 413
```

I've reloaded the service, as well as uninstalled mongo and reinstalled

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the WiredTiger.wt files that were generated on startup. There was a driver issue, so I looked to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26103) solution to fix the driver. Unfortunately, I didn't pay attention to the version that this came from, as well as other data-specific attributes that the *.wt files contain.

I had to remove the installation including all of the data. A completely fresh installation fixed the problem.

In short, didn't read instructions